# Calling a safeTransferFrom of a contract that implements an ERC721Upgradeable interface

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, interfaces

I have a contract A that inherits the following contracts:

```
contract NftTemplate is
    Initializable,
    ERC721Upgradeable,
    ERC721URIStorageUpgradeable,
    AccessControlUpgradeable,
    INftTemplate
```

I want to call the "safeTransferFrom" of this contract from another one. In the other contract called "B" I'm importing the interface INftTemplate. This is the interface:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

interface INftTemplate {
    function safeMint(
        address to,
        string memory _uri,
        bool _isTransferable //onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE)
    ) external;

    function getNextTokenIdCounter() external view returns (uint256);

    function isNftTransferable(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (bool);

    function contractURI() external view returns (string memory);

    function contractOwner() external view returns (address);

    function safeTransferFromWrapper(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _tokenId
    ) external;

    function safeTransferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _tokenId
    ) external;

    function getType() external view returns (string memory);
}
```

This is the safeTransferFrom function of contract A:

```
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public override (ERC721Upgradeable, INftTemplate, IERC721Upgradeable) {
        safeTransferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId);
    }
```

This causes errors when safeTransferFrom is called:

```
     Error: Transaction reverted and Hardhat couldn't infer the reason.
    at NftTemplate.safeTransferFrom (contracts/NftTemplate.sol:179)
```

I'm trying to call the function like so:

```
INftTemplate(collectionAddress).safeTransferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            _itemInfo.idInCollection
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have created an **infinite loop in contract A**, since safeTransferFrom is calling itself. If you wanted to call safeTransferFrom of the inherited contract, you should use the super keyword like:

```
function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public 
  override (ERC721Upgradeable, INftTemplate, IERC721Upgradeable) {
        super.safeTransferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId);
}
```